# using apostrophe with python's subprocess

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, command-line, subprocess

seems like I can't use apostrophe, the command fails with no informative error.
I'm trying to execute the following:

```
    secretLsCmd      = subprocess.Popen(('docker', 'secret', 'ls')     , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    oneWhitespaceCmd = subprocess.Popen(('tr', '-s','" "')             , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=secretLsCmd.stdout)
    onlySecretsCmd   = subprocess.check_output(('cut', "-d' '", '-f2') , stdin=oneWhitespaceCmd.stdout)
```

in a normal Linux terminal, it would execute the following command:

```
docker secret ls | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Running this command in CLI works fine, but once I put it in python it isn't working. The 2 first commands in the pipe are working fine (i have checked), the last command is not working, exiting with error code 1... I'm almost 100% sure it is the -d' ' , but how can I fix that? any idea?

Comment: use a backslash before the apostrophe like : `\'`, it should work

Comment: already tried that.. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
oneWhitespaceCmd = subprocess.Popen(('tr', '-s','" "'), ...)
```

is actually running:

```
tr -s '" "'
```

so you want to lose the extra double quotes there: Python will quote any arguments that it need to quote for the shell.

This command:

```
onlySecretsCmd   = subprocess.check_output(('cut', "-d' '", '-f2'), ...)
```

is equivalent to the shell command:

```
cut '-d'"'"' '"'"'' -f2
```

so again, you probably just want to lose the quotes round the whitespace:

```
onlySecretsCmd   = subprocess.check_output(('cut', "-d ", '-f2'), ...)
```

and leave it to Python to insert quotes where required. This will actually run (what should be equivalent to what you want though not identical):

```
cut '-d ' -f2
```

I used `shlex.quote()` to create a shell equivalent to the commands you are running, though in practice unless you tell `subprocess` to invoke a shell it will just be executing the equivalent of the command bash would execute after parsing all the escape quote marks. So internally the escaping isn't happening but the quotes to distinguish the arguments aren't needed either.